# Classification with groups of samples

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have the following example data set

```
family    name    weight    height    kid
smith     john    70        1.7       0
smith     mary    65        1.7       0
smith     lucy    40        1.1       1
jones     marc    45        1.5       1
jones     ted     30          1       1
miller    sue     55        1.6       0
miller    bill    80        1.7       0
miller    ava     40        1.4       1
```

In a typical classification problem, one goal could be to maximize the correct classification of 'kids' samples, i.e., a perfect classifier output for the table above would be [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1].

Lets say I am not concerned about the correct classification of all the kids samples, but I would like as output, predictions that maximize the number of families with at least one correctly identified kid sample. Within this second approach outputs [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] and [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1] would be perfect predictions (all 3 families (smith, jones, miller) with at least one kid sample classified correctly).

Imagine we have prediction_1 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1] (1 single mismatch in lucy smith, 2 families (jones, miller) with at least one kid classified correctly) and prediction_2 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1] (1 single mismatch in ted jones, all 3 families with at least one kid classified correctly). Is there any way (e.g. customized loss function as @stans has suggested), for the algorithm to learn that prediction_2 is better? (in a standard approach both predictions, having 1 mismatch, would be considered equally right/wrong).

Answer (score 0):

You just run some of the usual classification algorithms (e.g. boosted trees or random forests) with an unusual loss function. The loss function applies a severe penalty to classification tables where 1 or more diagonal elements are 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I have understood correctly, in the approach you suggest the penalization scheme does not consider the family/group condition. For example, using the example table, prediction1 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1] would have the same penalization value as prediction2 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], but I would like prediction1 to be more penalized than prediction2, since the number of families with at least one correctly predicted sample are 2 for prediction1 and 3 for prediction2.

Comment: In that case your penalty = [Big number] * [Number of 0 diagonal elements]